# apply.yearly() works with subset but not on full time series dataset in R

Tags: r, function, data-structures, subset, xts

When I run the following code on my dataset, I get an output (partial one shown) like this:

```
all_countries_ts[,grepl("Muslims", colnames(all_countries_ts))]

             Senegal Muslims Serbia Muslims Seychelles Muslims
1970-01-01         3693807         200000                170
2000-01-01         8936283         529322                730
2010-01-01        11713126         527598                821
2015-01-01        13621382         471414                844
```

However, when I try to use the function apply.yearly on it to sum across the years, I just get an NA result:

```
apply.yearly(all_countries_ts[,grepl("Muslims", colnames(all_countries_ts))], FUN = sum)

1970-01-01   NA
2000-01-01   NA
2010-01-01   NA
2015-01-01   NA
```

The funny thing is that it works with some inputs but not others. For example, if I use input "Agnostics" instead of "Muslims", I get a good result. There isn't an error, so I can't seem to figure out what exactly is happening here.

all_countries_ts is stored as a xts object. One thing to note is that apply.yearly() always work on a subset of this dataset. I have written a function and you can see it below:

```
sum_by_category <- function(religious_group, dataset) {
apply.yearly(dataset[,grepl(paste(religious_group), colnames(dataset))], FUN = 
sum)
}

country_search <- function(country_name, z){
  z <- foreach(i = 1:length(country_name), .combine = merge.xts) %do%{
    all_countries_ts[,grepl(country_name[i], colnames(all_countries_ts))]
  }
  return(z)}
```

When I type in the following, it works perfectly:

```
sum_by_category("Muslims", country_search("Senegal"))
               Senegal Muslims
1970-01-01         3693807
2000-01-01         8936283
2010-01-01        11713126
2015-01-01        13621382
```

I really can't figure out what's going on since it works with some inputs and not others. Thanks in advance for any help / insights!

Comment: How can we reproduce this issue? Sharing your data by copy-pasting `dput(...)` is a start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xts::apply.yearly` expects `x` argument coercible to `xts` object. Perhaps your data.frame is not a `xts` compatible data frame.

The help for `apply.yearly` explains:

> **Arguments**
>
> ```
> x     an time-series object coercible to xts
> FUN   an R function
> ```

I have created a sample data based on data shared by `OP` and converted it to `xts` class. `apply.yearly` works correctly on the same.

```
library(xts)

# Convert data.frame to xts class
all_countries_ts <- xts(df[,-1], order.by = df$Date)

#Now one can use `apply.yearly`
apply.yearly(all_countries_ts[,grepl("Muslims", colnames(all_countries_ts))], FUN = sum)

#                [,1]
# 1970-01-01  3893977
# 2000-01-01  9466335
# 2010-01-01 12241545
# 2015-01-01 14093640
```

**Edited:** Review of the OP's data suggest that it contains `NA` for many column which is causing total sum to be shown as `NA`. The fix is simple. OP needs to use as:

```
apply.yearly(all_countries_ts[,grepl("Muslims",colnames(all_countries_ts))],
                FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)

#                  [,1]
# 1970-01-01  570772699
# 2000-01-01 1292170756
# 2010-01-01 1571250533
# 2015-01-01 1734531709
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
" Date             'Senegal Muslims' 'Serbia Muslims' 'Seychelles Muslims' Others
1970-01-01         3693807         200000                170               200
2000-01-01         8936283         529322                730              100
2010-01-01        11713126         527598                821              300
2015-01-01        13621382         471414                844              500",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#convert Date column to Date format
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
```

Comment: @Sunny I have updated my answer. Your data contain's `NA` for few columns. As `NA` are contagious its changing total sum to `NA` . You have to additional argument for `sum` as `na.rm = TRUE`.